# Cannot import one csproj but CAN import another. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2019

I have a Visual Project called 'Consumer', in which I'm importing references to two other visual studio projects. I'm doing the import in Consumer's CSPROJ file like this:

*GUIDs have been randomized*

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\InMemoryCacheSearch\src\ProductDetailSearchTests\InMemoryCacheSearch.FunctionalTests.ProductDetailSearchTests.csproj">
        <Project>{DE7350B2-8191-4622-A188-5513F00F7B3E}</Project>
        <Name>AwesomeCorp.InMemoryCacheSearch.FunctionalTests.ProductDetailSearchTests</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\InMemoryCacheSearch\src\Common\InMemoryCacheSearch.FunctionalTests.Common.csproj">
        <Project>{347F3782-4FFB-45EA-93B4-D78B3159DC94}</Project>
        <Name>AwesomeCorp.InMemoryCacheSearch.FunctionalTests.Common</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

However in Consumer's code, if I do the following two `using`:

```
using InMemoryCacheSearch.FunctionalTests.ProductDetailSearchTests;
using InMemoryCacheSearch.FunctionalTests.Common;
```

... only the second one is seen and not the first one .... ***and I can't figure out WHY !?***

Apart from their own imports of other things, the CSPROJ files of both the projects I'm trying to import are the same, setup wise. There's only one parameter in `Common`s CSPROJ which the other doesn't have, and that's this:

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>True</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

And I don't think NOT having this in `ProductDetailSearchTests` CSPROJ file limits me from importing it.

Any advice ?

Comment: Project reference and namespace are different things. You should check the actual namespace in `InMemoryCacheSearch.FunctionalTests.ProductDetailSearchTests` as well as default, which is set in `csproj`

Comment: Yep I know. I checked the namespace in `ProductDetailSearchTests` and it's what I'm using.

Comment: In the case here, the relevant namespaces that I'm trying to access from both projects are basically the same name as the csproj filenames, `InMemoryCacheSearch.FunctionalTests.Common` and `InMemoryCacheSearch.FunctionalTests.ProductDetailSearchTests` (copied and pasted here from two class files inside those namespaces).